# Add custom rest header in api is not working

Tags: spring, rest, http-headers

I need to call a third party api via my own api. The third party api required custom headers for authentication, which i do not want exposed to client side. So what i did is add custom header and call the third party api in my api. But it is not working.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/downloadCompletedDocument/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> download(@PathVariable("id") String id, @RequestHeader Map header)
{
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("userloginname", "testUser");
    headers.set("organizationkey", "testOrganization");
    HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<byte[]> responseObj = restTemplate
            .exchange(url + id, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity,
                    byte[].class);
    return responseObj;
}
```

But when i use the tool by passing the header, it could work successfully. This is what i am not understand.

[image]

PS: I have tried filter, but same result.

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException
{

    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    MutableHttpServletRequest mutableRequest = new MutableHttpServletRequest(req);
    Enumeration<String> a = req.getHeaderNames();
    mutableRequest.putHeader("userloginname", "testUser");
    mutableRequest.putHeader("organizationkey", "testOrganization");
    Enumeration<String> b = mutableRequest.getHeaderNames();
    chain.doFilter(mutableRequest, response);
}
```

Comment: Please provide little more details for my understanding, 1. Are you able to invoke third-party api via postman(or the rest client tool which you use). If yes, put a **logger** in your code and print the header details & url - ensure both postman headers + url combination is equivalent to what it prints in the console. 2. Are you able to invoke your local api from postman?

Comment: @Govind Yes. i can invoke third-party api and my api via rest client tool. The problem is when i pass authentication header via tool, i got the pdf i want from third-party api. But when i remove the header from tool, and "hardcoded" in my api, i got the response status 401. I believe the "hardcoded" header did not work when i invoke the third-party api.

Comment: I believe you're able to invoke your local api and 401 is throwing at the third-party url.. with that said, can you try adding the below content type in your code and see if that works? headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

Comment: Sadly, it does not work.

Comment: Am sorry content type should be either APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM or APPLICATION_PDF. Try the below and see if that works as well. RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(); restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add( new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter()); HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders(); headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM));

Comment: No luck. I try to avoid other possibility may affect the result by creating a new project with only 1 controller to test. I am pretty sure the mistake is within this method, but i couldn't find out.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by changing the third party api url from http to https. Not sure why this does not affect the rest client tool.